# Responsive Website Dropdown form issue

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I am having a bit of a problem with a form on a drop down in the foundation 5 framework.

Basically I am assigning an input field and button to a dropdown menu, which works fine.

But as I can't firstly see a Back button like I can on the first dropdown, I can't see any reasons why. When basic code is a replication.

After viewing the second dropdown and going back to the menu to view dropdown one the input field and button are visible...

Source code below:

CSS:

```
      .has-form-small {

        top: 0rem;
        left: 0rem;
        min-width: 15rem; }
      @media only screen and (max-width: 40em) {
        .has-form {
          min-width: 10rem;
          top: 0 rem; }
        .has-form .button {
          height: 3rem; } }
    </style>
```

HTML:
Dropdown 1:

```
<section class='top-bar-section'>
  <!-- Right Nav Section -->
  <ul class='right'>
    <li><a href='#'>Button</a></li>
    <li class='has-dropdown'>
      <a href='#'>Dropdown</a>
      <ul class='dropdown'>
        <li><a href='#'>link</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Dropdown 2:

```
    <section class='top-bar-section'>
      <!-- Right Nav Section-->
      <strong class='show-for-small-only'>
      <ul class='right'>
        <li class='has-dropdown'>
          <a href='#'>Dropdown2</a>
          <ul class='dropdown'>
              <li class='has-form-small'>
                <div class='row collapse'>
                  <div class='large-9 small-9 columns'>
                    <input type='text' placeholder='Find Stuff'>
                </div>
                <div class='large-3 small-3 columns'>
                    <a href='#' class='alert button expand'>Search</a>
                </div>
                </div>
              </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      </strong>
    </section>
```

Comment: I think you need to have another go at describing exactly what the problem is. It's difficult to understand you. Also, can you break up the code you posted and only show what you feel are the relevant parts?

Comment: Just edited it. Hopefully it's clearer.

Comment: Thanks, that's clearer. I'll let the community respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix in the end. Turns out a drop down menu option isn't needed.

Code as below:

CSS:

```
    <style>
  .has-form-small {
    color: darkslategray;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0rem;
    left: 0rem;
    min-width: 26rem;
    min-height: 2.7rem;}
  @media only screen {
    .has-form-small {
      color: darkslategray;
      min-width: 26rem;
      min-height: 2.7rem;
      top: 0rem; }
    .has-form-small .button {
      color: darkslategray;
      width:  10rem;}}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<nav class='top-bar' data-topbar role='navigation'>
    <ul class='title-area'>
      <li class='name'>
        <h1><a href='#'>My Site</a></h1>
      </li>
      <strong class='hide-for-small-only'>
      <li class='has-form'>
        <div class='row collapse'>
          <div class='large-9 small-9 columns'>
            <input type='text' placeholder='Find Stuff'>
          </div>
          <div class='large-3 small-3 columns'>
            <a href='#' class='alert button expand'>Search</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      </strong>
      <!-- Remove the class 'menu-icon' to get rid of menu icon. Take out 'Menu' to just have icon alone -->
      <li class='toggle-topbar menu-icon'><a href='#'><span>Menu</span></a></li>
    </ul>

    <section class='top-bar-section'>
      <!-- Right Nav Section -->
      <ul class='right'>
        <li><a>&nbsp</a></li>
        <li>
        <strong class='show-for-small-only'>
          <li class='has-form-small'>
              <div class='large-12 small-9 columns'>
                <input type='text' placeholder='Find Stuff'>
              </div>
              <div class='large-3 small-3 columns'>
                <a href='#' class='alert button expand'>Search</a>
              </div>
          </li>
        </strong>
        </li>
      </ul>



      <ul class='right'>
        <li><a href='#'>Button</a></li>
        <li class='has-dropdown'>
          <a href='#'>Dropdown</a>
          <ul class='dropdown'>
            <li><a href='#'>link</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <!-- Left Nav Section -->
      <ul class='left'>

      </ul>
    </section>
  </nav>
```

There may be better ways to do this (e.g. remove blank row with "&nspb") but I was having issues with background colours, and this is supposed to only be a demo site.